# I minted an NFT by mistake while in Rinkeby Test net on my wallet, the NFT sold for 1eth now it’s in my test wallet how do I recover this ETH?

Tags: metamask, rinkeby, nft, test

This is the details of the transfer

Buyer
my1703

Transaction hash
0x5438b317f970448a040bba32b89c1e2c4ae306943764193a19d7e65739ae2283

You earned
1.007224 ETH
Type of transaction
Purchase
Time sent
Sun Mar 21 2021 07:12:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, it's in your test wallet. What else do you need, since you have the test Ethers there?

If you mint it in a testnet and someone buys it, they buy it with testnet Ethers, which has no monetary value. So you have gained 1 of testnet Ethers.

The transaction of 1 Eth only exists in the Rinkeby testnet (https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x5438b317f970448a040bba32b89c1e2c4ae306943764193a19d7e65739ae2283).

Comment: The person who bought the NFT wouldn’t know I had mistakenly minted the NFT in test net though, and would had paid with real ETH is that not correct?

Comment: I didn’t purposely mint the NFT in test net it was a mistake I only realised when I tried to send ETH to a different wallet and it never showed up, so what you’re saying it the ETH that’s in Rinkeby test is not actually real ETH even though the customer paid from his normal wallet?

Comment: Added details to my answer. Only Rinkeby Ethers were transferred.

Comment: Hi Lauri yes I understand the Eth is in the Rinkeby test net scan, what my concern is that the customer didn’t know they were sending Eth to my test net wallet so it would be real Eth sent, my question is how do I recover the real Eth out of my test net onto main net.

Comment: I'm not going to repeat myself anymore. The transaction is only in Rinkeby, not in mainnet. Only Rinkeby Ethers were transferred. A user can't send Ether between different networks, not even by accident. A testnet wallet can only contain assets inside that network.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I’m new to this so please don’t be short with me, everyone makes mistakes and I just wanted a professional to talk me through it.